# Can you reference the textboxes on an ssrs report from embedded code

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

Is it possible to reference a textbox from the embedded code of a ssrs report.  I would like to show or hide the textbox based on a condition.

Comment: why do you want to reference the textbox? I would have code return values to textbox properties and such but not the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to do this is to put a condition on the visible property of your textbox.
For example, the Visibility.Hidden property of your textbox, put your condition like this:

```
=If(CONDITION, True, False)
```

So, if your condition is True - set Hidden = True
and if your condition is False- set Hidden = False

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Although I still used custom code per the comment above.
Seth

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [ReportItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934329.aspx) collection...